# not all variables bound (Simple query)

Tags: sql, oracle

I've written a super simple test trying to get a value stored in l_numTables and it keeps throwing the error "not all variables bound". There's only one variable. It's a number and should work fine with the return data type from COUNT(*). Is there anything I'm missing here? (Moving from SSMS to Oracle has been rough)

```
declare l_numTables number := 0;

begin
    select COUNT(*) 
      into :l_numTables 
      from all_tab_columns 
     where column_name like '%TEST%';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_numTables);
end;
```

Comment: Remove the colon from `:l_numTables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INTO` clause is not part of the `SELECT` statement, it's exclusively a PL/SQL construct. `l_numTables` is not a bind variable (it is **not** part of the SQL statement, even though it appears in the middle of it). Remove the colon prefix, and see what happens - I didn't check the rest to see if it's OK.

Comment: Brilliant, that did it. Thank you, Mathguy!